# Gnuplot's calculation is incorrect

Tags: gnuplot, orbital-mechanics

I try to plot the orbital velocity with gnuplot, but somehow gnuplot gets completely different results than me. Now from experience I think my values are correct but I checked it with Google's calculator and get my results.

I use the formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit#Velocity) and [Google gets a velocity at apoapsis of about 2.2 km/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit#Velocity). Now gnuplot itself gets a velocity of about 3.2 km/s.

```
set xlabel "Altitude above sea level (meters)"
set ylabel "Orbital velocity (meters per second)"
set title "Velocity of an 80×100 km orbit around Kebrin"
set terminal png size 800,640
set output "orbitv.png"
set xrange [80000:100000]
G=6.674*10**-11
M=5.2915793*10**22
R=600000
plot sqrt(G*M*(2/(x+R)-1/(90000+R))) title 'Orbital velocity' with lines
```

[image: This is the resulting graph]

I'm wondering were did I make the mistake? I copied the formula directly to Google and replaced `G`, `M` and `R` with the constant values and `x` with 100000 and get the result linked above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has to do with how gnuplot handles integers when doing arithmetic.  When you have an expression like `1/(90000 + R)`, if `R` is an integer, gnuplot evaluates `1/(690000) = 0`, which is perfectly valid integer arithmetic.  The solution is to add a period to a number so that gnuplot knows to cast it as a floating-point number:

```
R = 600000.     # short option
R = 600000.0    # clearer option
```

Another solution is to use e-notation for big numbers:

```
R = 6e5
```

Gnuplot treats that as a float.  This also helps prevent order-of-magnitude/number-of-zeroes errors.

Incidentally, python and other languages have the same problem with integer arithmetic--watch out!